# Select2 is not showing dropdown, clear, or any other images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I think I am missing something here.

Select2 is working fine in my MVC application, except, it is not showing dropdown image, search image, clear image, or I should say any other image which is a part of this plugin.

Following is how I have used it in my page:

1) Razor view

> ```
> <div>
> <input id="countriesList" type="hidden" class="bigdrop"/>
> </div>
> ```

2) Script

```
$('#countriesList').select2(
{
    placeholder: 'Select Countries',
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    maximumSelectionSize: 3,
    multiple: true,
    allowClear:true,
    ajax: {
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCountriesList", "Geography")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                searchTerm: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
        return {
            results: data 
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Also, I have copied select2 files (i.e. js, css, images, and all) in the same folder structure as they were downloaded from its site, and I can see CSS and JS being loaded as well. It seems I am not using appropriate classes due to which images are not getting loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out myself.
While bundling used in an MVC application, the style bundles must have names similar to physical folder containing CSS.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. How exactly did you fix it?

Comment: For example, your Select2 styles are under "../Contents/Select2/css" folder then your style bundle name should also contain similar path.. For example "~/Contents/Select2/Styles" Let me know if that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem and i think @Nirman's answer is not good (for) me.
because if the bundle and directory has same name. mvc has been confused and not loads css and other contents that placed in that directory.

look at the 2nd part of second answer of this post.
it shows the conflict between same name of bundles and directories:

[Do not use folder paths as bundle names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423253/mvc-bundling-failed-to-load-resource)

it says:
"2. Do not use folder paths as bundle names"