# bootstrap - Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bundles

I have an aspnet mvc application My bootstrap bundle could not be loaded in browser

**BundlesConfig**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
...
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js", 
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"));
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 </head>
<body>
    <div> ... <div>
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Now when i load the page view source says

```
<script src="/Home/~bundles/bootstrap"></script> Failed to load resource
```

Why is it giving the wrong address all other scripts are found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below link , the answer mention by the **gone coding user** , has clearly explained what are the ways  we can do ,to avoid this error .

[MVC Bundling - Failed to load resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423253/mvc-bundling-failed-to-load-resource)

Kindly take a look and let me know whether that solved your problem .

Thanks
karthik